# Facebook Api and Construct2 game Score

Tags: facebook-graph-api, construct-2, facebook-graph-api-v2.4

I am Ishtiak Ahmed, studying in CSE dept of Islamic University of Technology and I’m from Bangladesh.

I am new to construct2. I’ve liked the game engine very much. For that reason I chose to make a game for my final project of 3rd year using Construct 2.

The game is an infinite runner game and I’m Making it for Facebook. I’ve used Facebook scoreboard for storing the score of my game user.

But the matter of fact is I am not able to see the scores of other players. I need the scores of the users of my game. But I am unable to do that.

Using Facebook’s graph API I can see only my score. But My teacher told me to implement such a thing so that I can see all the player score’s even who are not in my friend-list.

When I tried that I faced problem of getting user access token. But how can I get the access token using construct 2 . Is it possible to see all the scores of my game user. Please help me . I am in a great danger :(

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe as far as Construct 2 goes working with Facebook, that you can only show scores of your friends who also play the game.

From this link: https://www.scirra.com/tutorials/58/how-to-make-a-facebook-game/page-5

> Note that hi-score tables only show scores for the current user and
>   their friends. You can't see all player's scores. This is how the
>   Facebook Scores system works.

To allow others to see your score, you must use the Facebook object and login with the "user_friends" permission. The issue then is getting your friends to play the game just once to set a score. Then you should be able to see them. :)

For using the Facebook object and scoring you need only the APP ID and the APP Secret available on the Facebook developer dashboard for your app.